# Using alembic.config.main redirects log output

Tags: python, logging, alembic, python-logging

I have a script that performs database operations alongside an alembic API call to upgrade a newly created database to head. I am having an issue with a python logger instance where logs are written to a file using a module level logger.

Then the script invokes `alembic.config.main(argv=alembic_args)` to run a migration. However, every log statement after the alembic call, using the original logger instance, isn't written to the expected log file.

Here is an example script that reproduces the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import os

import alembic.config

from .utilities import get_migration_dir

logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

CUR_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
LOG = logging.getLogger('so_log')

LOG.info('Some stuff')
LOG.info('More stuff')

alembic_config = (
    '--raiseerr',
    'upgrade', 'head'
)

os.chdir(get_migration_dir())

alembic.config.main(argv=alembic_config)

os.chdir(CUR_DIR)

LOG.debug('logging after alembic call.')
LOG.debug('more logging after alembic call.')
print('Code still running after alembic')
```

Log file output

```
INFO:so_log:Some stuff
INFO:so_log:More stuff
```

stdout

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
print statement before alembic
Code still running after alembic
```

It seems as though the logger instance, `LOG`, is losing context or being directed elsewhere after calling the alembic API.

Also, I've tried running the alembic call in a separate thread which yielded the same result. What I expect to happen should be that log statements continue to write to the specified file after using alembic for migrations but that is not happening. And further, it's actually breaking the `LOG` instance for any code that's called afterward; Unless I'm just missing something here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because alembic sets up logging using `fileConfig` from `alembic.ini`, you can see it in your `env.py` script:

```
# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
```

This effectively overrides your original logger config.

To avoid this, you can simply remove this line from `env.py`, however this will result in no logs being produced when running `alembic` from console.

A more robust option is to run alembic commands via `alembic.command` instead of `alembic.config.main`. This way you can override alembic config at runtime:

```
from alembic.config import Config
import alembic.command

config = Config('alembic.ini')
config.attributes['configure_logger'] = False

alembic.command.upgrade(config, 'head')
```

Then in `env.py`:

```
if config.attributes.get('configure_logger', True):
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I ended up running the alembic command in a separate process at runtime. Your solution is much better. Thank you.

Comment: This is a great solution. I'd like to also recommend that we use the Config instantiation to set our configure_logger value instead of `config.attributes`. ie. `config = Config('alembic.ini', attributes={'configure_logger': False})`

Answer (score 23):

I just learned that fileConfig takes a keyword argument, disable_existing_loggers, which defaults to True. Simply adding `disable_existing_loggers = False` to the call to fileConfig in `env.py`
e.g:

```
fileConfig(config.config_file_name, disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

appears to allow both logging configurations to work without interfering with each other (which may be preferred rather than having to choose one over the other, in some cases)

Comment: This SHOULD be the answer.

Comment: Disable existing logger flag worked for me in FASTAPI based application. However I started seeing each message being logged twice. I had to use this flag in my FastApi logger : propogate = False .

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone comes across this issue here is what worked for me:

- Updating the `fileConfig` call in `env.py`:
  `fileConfig(config.config_file_name, disable_existing_loggers = False)`
- Updating the level for `[logger_root]` in `alembic.ini` to a lower level, since it is set by default to `WARN`